# Setting OpenLayers filter with PropertyName?

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to get a feature with a `getFeature` request that filters features by their unique `id` with `IsLike`. This is the filter on the `POST` request:

```
<GetFeature xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" outputFormat="application/json" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
    <Query typeName="CP:CadastralParcel" srsName="EPSG:25830">
        <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
                <PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" singleChar="." escapeChar="!">
                <PropertyName>CP:nationalCadastralReference</PropertyName>
                <Literal>1010001</Literal>
            </PropertyIsLike>
        </Filter>
    </Query>
</GetFeature>
```

The problem is that the request returns an empty feature collection. Also tried with `PropertyIsEqualTo` (EqualTo filter) but I'm still getting an empty feature collection.

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":"unknown","features":[],"crs":null}
```

The features are like this: [Feature example](https://inspire.navarra.es/services/CP/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=CP:CadastralParcel&maxFeatures=1)

I have the `id=1010001`, so I can get/identify the feature with

- `<CP:CadastralParcel gml:id="ES.RRTN.CP.1010001">`
- `<base:localId>1010001</base:localId>`
- `<CP:nationalCadastralReference>1010001</CP:nationalCadastralReference>`

How can I set this in the OpenLayers filter? Note that so far I have implemented it this way:

```
var featureRequest = new WFS().writeGetFeature({
   srsName: 'EPSG:25830',
   featurePrefix: 'CP',
   featureTypes: ['CadastralParcel'],
   outputFormat: 'application/json',
   filter: likeFilter('CP:nationalCadastralReference', '1010001')
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved with `EqualTo` filter:

```
filter: equalToFilter('nationalCadastralReference', this.myinput, false)
```

Adding the third parameter seems to solve the issue. Now the filter on the request is as following:

```
<GetFeature xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" outputFormat="application/json" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
    <Query typeName="CP:CadastralParcel" srsName="EPSG:25830">
        <PropertyName>CP:geometry</PropertyName>
        <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <PropertyIsEqualTo matchCase="false">
                <PropertyName>nationalCadastralReference</PropertyName>
                <Literal>1010001</Literal>
            </PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </Filter>
    </Query>
</GetFeature>
```